# issue with how to render with react router

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this specific case where if the user routes to say topics/rendering, I need to show him a seperate Component and when user routes to topics/10, I need to show him another Component.
The problem I am facing right now is that even when I do topics/rendering, I see both of the components being rendered on screen.
Also when user routes to topics/math/10,
I need to route him to a different page.

Here is the routing part in my App.js (default App.js)

```
<div className="App">
    <Router>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
      <Route path="/about" component={About} />
      <Route exact path="/topics" component={Topics} />
      <Route exact path ="/topics/rendering" component={Description}/>
      <Route  exact path="/topics/:id" component={Topic} />
      <Route path="/topics/:description/:id" component={TopicExtended}/>
    </Router>
  </div>
```

Comment: use `<Switch>` to render only the first matching route https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Switch

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to wrap the `Route` components in a [`Switch`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Switch) component so that only one of them will be rendered at a time.

```
<div className="App">
  <Router>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
      <Route path="/about" component={About} />
      <Route path="/topics" component={Topics} />
      <Route path="/topics/rendering" component={Description} />
      <Route path="/topics/:id" component={Topic} />
      <Route path="/topics/:description/:id" component={TopicExtended} />
    </Switch>
  </Router>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should put Route tags inside Switch tag

```
<Router>
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
    <Route path="/about" component={About} />
    <Route path="/topics" component={Topics} />
    <Route path ="/topics/rendering" component={Description}/>
    <Route path="/topics/:id" component={Topic} />
    <Route path="/topics/:description/:id" component={TopicExtended}/>
  </Switch>
</Router>
```

but import it first `import {Switch} from 'react-router-dom'`